# Object tag PDF scrolling in Edge/IE11

Tags: html, object, internet-explorer, scroll, microsoft-edge

Does anyone know how to allow for pdf scrolling in Edge/IE11 for HTML object tags? In Chrome it seems to scroll just fine. I've tried adding overflow scroll and switching to iframe and adding and embed tag

```
 <object scrolling="yes" id="content-doc" data={url+"#toolbar=0&view=Fit,top"} type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100vh">
        <p>It appears you don&apos;t have a PDF plugin for this browser.
        You can <a href={url}>click here to
        download the PDF file.</a></p>
 </object>
```

Comment: I tested with your code and replaced `data` value with a local pdf file like this `data="filev1.pdf"`. It can scroll well in IE 11 and Microsoft Edge. The result is like this: [in IE 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPjVW.gif), [in Microsoft Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHNoE.gif). I use Adobe Acrobat Reader in IE 11 to display pdfs. Are you using other pdf plugins which cause this issue? Or could you provide a minimal example which can [reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Yeah i think that was the issue - i ended up using google doc viewer to display it and it ended up working. thanks!